# Doubts on order() function

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have a list with two related variables: "Name" and "Score"

I want to order the list by Score, and if two people have the same 'Score' then it should be ordered by alphabetically by name. However, when I try this, the tie-breaker is its position on the list.

Is there a way to fix this?

```
         Name         Score
1        Rodrigo       100

2        Ramon          90

3        Eduardo        90
```

Then, after applying `order(list_name)`, I get:

```
         Name         Score

2        Ramon        90

3        Eduardo      90

1        Rodrigo       100
```

Comment: Are you sure that's a list or is it a dataframe?

Comment: Please provide a data example in a usable format.

Comment: amrrs it is, confirmed with typeof()

Comment: Take better a look at what `class(<yourList>)` returns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a dataframe by multiple column(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-multiple-columns)

Comment: Actually, when I apply class() it shows it is a data frame! Is there any special function for this case?